# How to write spaces and symbols in string formatting

Tags: python

string formatting error

Tried all kinds of string formatting no results found

```
msg.body = '''Dear admin, 

         You requested that your password be reset.
         Please visit the link below or copy and paste it into your browser to create a new password.%s''' \
                   %url_for('.get_resetpassword',token=token,_external=True)%'''

        Thank you,
         Team
        '''
```

builtins.TypeError
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: For python3 you can use fstrings. Those look more compact and readable. Read more about fstrings [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Comment: To make that clear: in Python 3.6+ you can use format strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use string format later:

```
msg.body = '''Dear admin, 

         You requested that your password be reset.
         Please visit the link below or copy and paste it into your browser to create a new password.%s  

        Thank you,
         Team
        '''%url_for('.get_resetpassword',token=token,_external=True)
```

So you don't need to bother with anything.

Or use:

```
msg.body = '''Dear admin, 

         You requested that your password be reset.
         Please visit the link below or copy and paste it into your browser to create a new password.%s''' \
                   %url_for('.get_resetpassword',token=token,_external=True)+'''

        Thank you,
         Team
        '''
```

Comment: If I use short msg,  It executes but this is long with a link in between

Comment: @vaseem See second one.

Comment: @vaseem Happy to help, :-), 

Answer (score 0):

This may work.

```
url_for="YOUR INPUT"
a='''Dear admin, 

     You requested that your password be reset.
     Please visit the link below or copy and paste it into your browser to create a new password.%s

     Thank you,
     Team.'''% (url_for)
```

print(a)